# Console to monitor hookup

Tags: display, console, connector

I would love to get a Wii (since the price dropped it seems like a good time to get one), however I do not currently have a TV to hook it up to. What hardware is suggested for hooking it up to a monitor? It only has 15Pin D-Sub, DVI-D inputs (the blue plug and the white plug).

Comment: Turns out that I ended up with a PS3 instead, I bought one of these: http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=3973799&CatId=3667 ... much better than a converter box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible, without buying some kind of converter box.  The Wii only outputs analog video.  There are converter boxes that will do analog to HDMI (which is DVI plus audio in a different connector), but they are almost as much as the Wii.  The best option, if you really wnated to do this, is buy a cheap TV.

Comment: That is unfortunate... oh well, I guess I can wait until my tv returns to me.

Answer (score 1):

Some monitors have Component inputs which means you could connect the Wii directly.  Unfortunately, it sounds like yours doesn't.

I would be wary of using a convertor box as these can produce lag which is obviously a problem if you're gaming.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to get a [Mayflash Wii to VGA cable](http://www.mayflash.com/?Products/NINTENDOWiiGC/VGA004.html), and then a VGA to DVI adapter.

Based on what I have read so far, it is more reliable (and easier) to get a converter that plugs directly into the Wii, rather than a "component to X" converter to attach to the Wii cables. I haven't seen a Wii to DVI cable or converter myself, though, hence the two-step suggestion above.

See also [my answer on what monitor to buy for a Wii](https://superuser.com/a/378558/29994).

Comment: this is based on investigation rather than personal experience